# epoll_wait() blocks prints to stdout

Tags: c, sockets, stdout, epoll

When using `epoll_wait`, it seems to "eat" everything that's written to `stdout` and delay the print until after `epoll_wait` has received an event, even though I tried to print before calling on anything related to epoll (it could even be at the beginning of my main method, it still won't get printed).

An example of prints that will not show until after `epoll_wait` has received an event:

```
printf("This doesn't get printed. ");
fprintf(stdout, "This doesn't get printed either.");
ev.events = EPOLLIN;
ev.data.fd = some_sock_fd; // Same with STDIN_FILENO
if (epoll_ctl(epoll_fd, EPOLL_CTL_ADD, some_sock_fd, &ev) == -1) {
    perror("epoll_ctl");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

for (;;) {
    rc = epoll_wait(epoll_fd, &ev, 1, -1);
    // This is where it gets printed
```

Writing to `stderr` works as normal, but how can I write to `stdout`? How do I prevent `epoll_wait` from blocking prints to `stdout`?

Comment: Not sure why that would happen. But you could try to explicitly flush stdout with `fflush(stdout);` after the print statements. Or turn off buffering altogether with `setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 0)`.

Comment: Thanks, I actually used `setbuf(stdout, NULL)` (shorter than `setvbuf`). `fflush(stdout)` also works. But I feel like these solutions are workarounds that don't address the core issue of epoll blocking the stdout buffer. It would be nice to know if this can be addressed within epoll itself.

Comment: epoll can hardly affect output that is done before the epoll calls. Is the stdout written directly to a tty device or is it redirected to pipe or file?

Comment: I seem to have fallen victim to my limited understanding of C and printf/stdout. This is simply a case of stdout being buffered because there's no newline. I've answered my own question below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue seems to be unrelated to `epoll_wait`. Here's a summary of the offending code:

```
// Since there's no newline, the following stays in the buffer
printf("Some print without newline.");

for (;;) {
    // At this point, the buffer has not been flushed,
    // and epoll_wait blocks the output
    rc = epoll_wait(epoll_fd, &ev, 1, -1);
```

Using `fflush(stdout)` *is* the solution to this code, since the buffering has nothing to do with epoll_wait, but with how the user-space buffers stdout:

```
// Since there's no newline, the following stays in the buffer
printf("Some print without newline.");

// Forces a write of user-space buffered data for stdout
fflush(stdout);

for (;;) {
    // At this point, the buffer has not been flushed,
    // and epoll_wait blocks the output
    rc = epoll_wait(epoll_fd, &ev, 1, -1);
```

To sum it up, this seems to be a case of looking in the wrong place for an issue that should have been obvious.